# An LSC, nonnegative sublinear functional is "bounded"

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> $X$ is a real Banach space, $p$ is a [sublinear functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublinear_function) on $X$ that is nonnegative and [lower semicontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) (in short, $\liminf p(x_n)\ge p(x)$ whenever $x_n\to x$). Then there exists $M<\infty$ such that $p(x)\le M\|x\|$.

I first defined $\phi(x)=\|x\|+p(x)+p(-x)$, and showed that $\phi$ is indeed a norm on $X$ and also dominates the original norm $\|\cdot\|$. Now if only I can show $(X,\phi)$ is complete, I'm done, since this would imply $\|\cdot\|$ and $\phi$ are equivalent and that in particular $p$ is dominated by $\phi$ and thus by $\|\cdot\|$.

I'm now mostly struggling to prove $p(x)$, or $p(x)+p(-x)$ is continuous at $0$. But I don't know how to use the lower semicontinuity here.

Comment: Would you be interested in a different argument, or only in continuations of yours?

Comment: @DanielFischer whatever help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That $p$ is lower semicontinuous means that its "closed unit ball", $B_p = p^{-1}([0,1])$ is closed. Since $p$ is sublinear and everywhere finite, $B_p$ is absorbing. By Baire's theorem, $B_p$ has nonempty interior. Since $B_p$ is convex, $0 \in \overset{\Large\circ}{B}_p$, hence there is an $r > 0$ such that $B_{\lVert\cdot\rVert}(0,r) \subset B_p$. By the sublinearity of $p$, it follows that

$$p(x) \leqslant \frac{1}{r}\lVert x\rVert$$

for all $x$.

Comment: A set $A\subset V$, where $V$ is a real or complex vector space is _absorbing_ if for every $v\in V$ there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $t\cdot v \in A$ for all scalars $t$ with $\lvert t\rvert < \varepsilon$. Here, we have $t\cdot x \in B_p$ if $\lvert t\rvert < \dfrac{1}{\max\{ p(x), p(-x)\}}$. (For $p(x) = p(-x) = 0$, the last means $t\cdot x \in B_p$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: thanks now I understand why $B_p$ has nonempty interior. But why $0\in\text{int}\, B_p$? I know that $B_p$ is convex and so is its interior and that $0\in B_p$, but how to conclude $0$ is in its intérieur as well?

Comment: If $x_0 \in \overset{\Large\circ}{B}_p$, pick $t \in [-1,0)$ such that $x_1 := t\cdot x_0 \in B_p$. By convexity, $\frac{1}{1+\lvert t\rvert}\cdot x_1 + \frac{\lvert t\rvert}{1+\lvert t\rvert}\cdot \overset{\Large\circ}{B}_p \subset B_p$, and the set on the left is open and contains $0$.

Comment: Incidentally, the argument shows a bit more: Dans un espace tonnelé, toute sous-norme semi-continue inférieurement est continue.

Comment: do you mean in a Banach space all SC seminorms are continuous? Lol I don't speak French actually, and the "intérieur" was just a typo due to the auto prediction of iOS keyboard. This function used to work fine until 10.0.1 or so when they enabled the multilingual auto prediction, which means even if you type in an English keyboard you get French word predictions (when I typed `interi` iPhone was quick to give `intérieur`). The bad news is this multilingual feature cannot be turned off, damn...

Comment: Ah, I got auto-fooled by technology. "In a barrelled space, every lower semicontinuous sub-norm is continuous". A sub-norm is a non-negative sublinear functional. Actually, that's an equivalence: a Hausdorff locally convex space is barrelled if and only if every lower semicontinuous seminorm is continuous, also if and only if every lower semicontinuous sub-norm is continuous.